# boost::mpl::accumulate のネスト

Tags: c++, boost

boost::mpl::accumulate や fold のネストはどうやったら実装できますか。

```
namespace mpl=boost::mpl;

typedef mpl::vector<mpl::int_<1>,mpl::int_<1>,mpl::int_<1>,mpl::int_<1>> vec1;
typedef mpl::vector<mpl::int_<2>,mpl::int_<2>,mpl::int_<2>,mpl::int_<2>> vec2;
typedef mpl::vector<mpl::int_<3>,mpl::int_<3>,mpl::int_<3>,mpl::int_<3>> vec3;
typedef mpl::vector<vec1,vec2,vec3> vvec;

typedef typename mpl::lambda
        <mpl::accumulate
            <mpl::_1 ,mpl::int_<0> ,mpl::plus<mpl::_1,mpl::_2> >
        >::type lam;

typedef typename mpl::accumulate
    <vvec
    ,mpl::int_<0>
    ,mpl::plus<mpl::_1,lam::template apply<mpl::_2>::type>
    >::type result;
```

このコードはコンパイルが通りませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Placeholder Expression](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/placeholder-expression.html)に対して、`type`を使うと、placeholderにplaceholderの番号を代入してメタ式を評価してしまいます。

また、lambdaの中にメタ式をネストしてplaceholderを使う場合、placeholderには、一番近いlambdaのメタ引数が束縛されてしまいます。その結果、lambdaの中のplus式にメタ値が代入されてしまって、これはもはや式ではないので、accumulateの評価の際に、第三メタ引数にメタ式ではなくメタ値があるのでエラーになるのだと思います。
これを防ぐためには、plusを別のlambdaで囲んで、外側のlambdaのメタ引数が束縛されないようにします。

以上を考慮すると以下の様にコードを修正すれば良いです。

```
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/apply.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/accumulate.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/plus.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;

typedef mpl::vector<mpl::int_<1>,mpl::int_<1>,mpl::int_<1>,mpl::int_<1>> vec1;
typedef mpl::vector<mpl::int_<2>,mpl::int_<2>,mpl::int_<2>,mpl::int_<2>> vec2;
typedef mpl::vector<mpl::int_<3>,mpl::int_<3>,mpl::int_<3>,mpl::int_<3>> vec3;
typedef mpl::vector<vec1,vec2,vec3> vvec;

typedef typename mpl::lambda<
    mpl::accumulate<
        mpl::_1, mpl::int_<0>, mpl::lambda<mpl::plus<mpl::_1, mpl::_2>>::type
    >
>::type lamb;

typedef typename mpl::accumulate<
    vvec
  , mpl::int_<0>
  , mpl::plus<mpl::_1, lamb::apply<mpl::_2>>
>::type result;


int main ()
{
    static_assert(result::value == 24, "");
}
```

上記のコードではテンプレートの`>>`等のC++11 specificな文法が一部使われているので、C++03でコンパイルする際は適切に変更してください。